# window.location.href not working in mobile device in an ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to open a view with a function call from UI side

```
<ion-option-button class="button-light icon ion-chatbubble" ng-click="openView('username')"></ion-option-button>
```

the controller code for the same is

```
$scope.openView=function(user){
        window.location.href ="/signin.html#/im?p=@"+user;
      };
```

Now this works perfectly in the browser but when I test this in mobile device I get the following error :-

> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///signin.html#im?p=username)

I know there are multiple ways and preferably one should use ui router etc but I have load the view of another angular app inside my app that is why I am somehow stuck on this.

Comment: got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

path on ionic should be relative, remove leading slash and try:

```
window.location.href ="signin.html#/im?p=@"+user;
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.openView=function(user){
        $state.go('app.signin');
    };

and `$state` defined in your controller.

Comment: Thanks Kaushal, But I can't use routers in my case. I don't get why the same code is working in browser and not in mobile device.

Comment: hello then try this for mobile:-    window.location = '#/signin.html#/im?p=@'+user;

Comment: Thanks, I tried it though it didn't work. Rather the app doesn't run on browser after the above change.